# Adding an external .ts file to an React App for compilation to a single .js file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, npm, service-worker

I'm trying to add a custom service worker to my React App.
For this to work, I need to register the service worker by calling

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('my-service-worker.js');
```

I want to code the worker in TypeScript, but I cannot figure out how to instruct npm to pack it separately, under a well-defined path, so i can register my worker with the path of the compiled .js file.

I tried creating a folder inside src/ with a tsconfig, setting an "outDir", but looks like I'm on the wrong track, since there's no matching js file created.